# TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function after deploying to Netlify?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tensorflow, netlify

Hello I am trying to deploy a web app to Netlify. It uses the COCO SSD model for object recognition in the frontend, which is purposeful. The web app works perfectly fine on localhost but once I deploy to Netlify I get this error:

```
detector.js:47 TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
    at r (classCallCheck.js:3)
    at new t (tensor.ts:266)
    at t.value (engine.ts:736)
    at i (tensor_ops_util.ts:75)
    at i (tensor.ts:55)
    at Module.p (io_utils.ts:223)
    at t.value (graph_model.ts:139)
    at t.<anonymous> (graph_model.ts:119)
    at c (runtime.js:63)
    at Generator._invoke (runtime.js:293)
```

I have never had this problem before and find it very odd, this is my code for implementation of the COCO SSD model and the class.

```
import React from 'react';
import Lottie from 'react-lottie';
import * as cocoSsd from '@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd';
import '@tensorflow/tfjs';

class Detector extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      count: 0,
      list: ['person','laptop','scissors','mouse', 'spoon', 'keyboard',],
      isStopped: true,
    }
  } 
  videoRef = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
      //getting camera permission code removed for readability
      const modelPromise = cocoSsd.load();
      Promise.all([modelPromise, webCamPromise])
        .then(values => {
          this.detectFrame(this.videoRef.current, values[0]);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    }
  }

  detectFrame = (video, model) => {
    model.detect(video).then(predictions => {
      this.checkPredictions(predictions);
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        this.detectFrame(video, model);
      });
    });
  };

  checkPredictions = predictions => {
    predictions.forEach(prediction => {
      if(prediction.class === this.state.list[0]) {
        const tempL = this.state.list;
        const tempC = this.state.count + 1;
        tempL.shift();
        this.setState({list: tempL, count: tempC, isStopped: false});
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        //removed for readability
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Detector;
```

Comment: How do you build your code? Previously I remember there was a same problem as build code with `target` with `es5` style

Comment: Sorry I'm a newbie so I don't entirely understand what you are asking, I'm guessing you are referring to making a production build? For that I run: npm run build in the console

Comment: :) I meant are you using babel and webpack and how did you configure them?

Comment: I see both babel and webpack in the package-lock.json but I have not taken any steps to configuring them. I created the app by running npx create-react-app name and installed a few node modules via npm. I believe anything related to babel and webpack has been auto generated by react.

Comment: Hmmm. If use `react-scripts`, it would hard to change since it's wrapped & configured itself unless you use `react-script-wired` which allows to custom the configuration. Are your repo accessible?

Comment: I just opened one: https://github.com/zhg-kj/scavhunt thank you for your continued help!

Comment: I did try to run your repo but it works normally though. Which node version are you using?

Comment: From running node -v in command line it says I am using v12.18.1.  The netlify app is deployed to scavhunt.netlify.app. I believe the problem only appears in deployment as it is perfectly fine when I run on localhost. Could it be an issue with the production build? Do you know if the production build does anything special that usually doesnt happen when just running npm start?

Comment: I have also tried deploying to github pages where the same error occurs, leading me to believe that it should definitely be a problem with production build?

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. I've dropped an suggestion for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `webpack` has picked the field (the built file) of `@tensorflow/tfjs` in case of production mode which ends up the problem.

But we can specify this field manually which describes here https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemainfields

In order to do it, you just simply switch to use `react-app-rewired` where we can customize `webpack` configuration. Here is the steps:

- Install

```sh
npm i -D react-app-rewired
```

- Create the override config file at the root repo `config-overrides.js` with following content:

```js
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
  {
    config.resolve.mainFields = ['main'];
  }
  return config;
}
```

- Switch to use `react-app-rewired` script by replacing the `react-scripts` commands:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-app-rewired start",
  "build": "react-app-rewired build",
  // ...  
},
```

Finally, you can run `npm build` and serve your built content to test it. That's it!

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for your help all this way, I literally can't thank you enough. If its worth anything, I opened a bounty and you'll be awarded with 100 points in 24 hours. Thank you for making my day :)